# How to check if we have error using angularJs $http method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJs factory its making call and working as expected but in terms of exception i have question what if we have exception after making call and it fails so in this case when i execute `prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory` i want to check first if there is any error display error and stay on same page.

How can i resolve this problem using below code ?

ctrl.js

```
 function deleteInventory(inventory,controlId) {
      prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory(inventory,controlId).then(function(){
        $scope.confirmationWin.close();
        $state.go('app.search');
      });
    }
```

factory.js

```
angular.module('App').factory('prcDeleteFactory',function($http){
  'use strict';
  return {
    deletePrcInventory: function(inventoryToDelete,key){
      return $http.get('app/delete/deleteInventory?inventoryToDelete=' + inventoryToDelete + '&key=' + key);
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "catch" error. If it happens promised returned by $http service gets rejected so you can handle it with catch (or error callback in `then`):

```
function deleteInventory(inventory,controlId) {
  prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory(inventory, controlId).then(function() {
    $scope.confirmationWin.close();
    $state.go('app.search');
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    $scope.error = 'Delete failed.';
  });
}
```

Comment: How about if we have error message from server that we need to display in case of failure ?

Comment: There is also the option to have a second function parameter inside `.then()` to handle situations where your server-side code runs and returns an error.

Comment: @hussain You could set some error message on the scope.

Comment: Maybe @hussain is unaware that the standard form of `.then()` is `.then(function successCallback(result){}, function errorCallback(error){});` You might consider adding that to your answer for completeness' sake.

Comment: @Lex I briefly mentioned it too, but anyway I wouldn't recommend error callback simply because it won't catch errors if they happen in the sibling success handler.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Good call.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the then / catch form :

```
 $http.get(/**/).then(function(response) {
    // do something with response
 }).catch(function(err) {
    // do something with error err
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `.then()`is the function that executes on error. Change your controller code to:

```
function deleteInventory(inventory,controlId) {
    prcDeleteFactory.deletePrcInventory(inventory,controlId).then(function(){
        $scope.confirmationWin.close();
        $state.go('app.search');
    }, function(error){
        //Some error occurred here
  });
}
```